# Exp-resso Store SSL error

Tags: expresso-store, php

My store has worked fine for me for the past several months using Paypal Express, then recently I started getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message '[curl] 60: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK.
Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed [url] https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp?METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=85.0&USER=****&PWD=****&SIGNATURE=****&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Authorization&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=25.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM=28&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=Order%20%2323&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL=https%3A%2F%2F****%2F%3FACT%3D42%26H%3Ded76259ef4afa5448b4a01476cc76f98&SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&LANDINGPAGE=Billing&RETURNURL=https%3A%2F%2F****%2F%3FACT%3D42%26H%3Ded76259ef4afa5448b4a01476cc76f98&CANCELURL=https%3A%2F%2F****&HDRIMG=&BRANDNAME=&NOSHIPPING=1&ALLOWNOTE=0&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=****&PAYMENTREQUEST in /home/****/system/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/guzzle/http/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php on line 338
```

(****)to signify sensitive data.

How do I get it to work again?

Comment: Which version of Store are you using?

Comment: This isn't specific to Store as such but the curl request is unable to verify the CA of the security certificate so it's throwing an exception. Have you recently moved the hosting at all and is this now on a Windows hosted setup?

Comment: No, hosting has been the same for the last 2 years. I'm on a dreamhost server. The only thing that has changed recently this updated EE to 2.8 and the Store to 2.31. But this error was present before both updates.

Comment: Very strange. Store (via one of the libraries we use, Guzzle) actually comes with the latest root CA certifies, which completely avoids most SSL problems. My guess is that your host has changed something without telling you (likely related to the recent heartbleed venerability, unless this started happening before April 7). Do you have a staging site on a different host/server you can test?

Comment: I do have a staging site on another server, but i don't have EE and the Store setup there. I have had problems before with this host, so I'm not surprised. What info/questions should I be looking for/asking?

Comment: Contacted Dreamhost support, they couldn't help me through live chat. but I sent a ticket in, so hopefully sometime in the future this may work again....

Comment: Since Dreamhost isn't getting this figured out very quickly is there another way to get this working again?

Comment: Dreamhost got back to me with this link to a possible fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/php-curl-https-causing-exception-ssl-certificate-problem-verify-that-the-ca-cer How do I use this in/with the Store? You said that Guzzle should already be doing this??